# Сложность в написании сортировки, используя lambda функции

Tags: c++, сортировка, lambda, лямбда-выражение

У меня есть два класса:

```
class A {
private:
   int m;
public:
   int getM() const { return m; }
}

class B {
private:
   std::vector<A *> array;
public:
   A *getArray(int i) const { return array[i]; }
   int arraySize() const { return array.size(); }
}
```

Так же есть указатель на класс B, обозначим его как b.

Я хочу отсортировать массив array по уменьшению значений m. То, что написал я ожидаемо не работает:

```
std::sort(b->getArray(0), b->getArray(b->arraySize()), [] (std::vector<A *> a1, std::vector<A *> a2) -> bool { return a1->getM() > a2->getM(); })
```

Вопрос: как правильно написать эту функцию sort, используя лямбды? Я конечно могу написать отдельно компаратор, но хотелось бы с лямбдами научиться взаимодействовать.

Comment: `std::sort` ожидает итераторы коллекции, а вы отдаете ей элементы массива, за пределы которого еще и выходите. Почему аргументы в лямбде - вектора, тоже вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем в `class B`

```
std::vector<A *>& getArray() { return array; }
```

и сортируем

```
B *b;
....
sort(b->getArray().begin(),b->getArray().end(),
     [](A* a, A* b){ return a->getM() > b->getM(); });
```

Или же в `class B` добавляем

```
void sortVector()
{
    sort(array.begin(),array.end(),
     [](A* a, A* b){ return a->getM() > b->getM(); });
}
```

и сортируем

```
B *b;
....
b->sortVector();
```